# how can i call the strings from a arraylist individually?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, jtable, jdatechooser

I'm making a program that will generate the dates between two dates. The dates are from a `DateChooser`. When I click a button the dates between the two dates is generated like this :

```
    date1 Jun 5, 2013  
    date2 June 20, 2013
```

Using this code

```
    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal2.setTime(toDate);
    while (cal2.getTime().before(newDateString)) {
        cal2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        String datelist=(format.format(cal2.getTime()));
        System.out.println(datelist);
```

It will generate this output

```
2013-06-18
2013-06-19
2013-06-20
2013-06-21
2013-06-22
2013-06-23
2013-06-24
2013-06-25
2013-06-26
2013-06-27
2013-06-28
2013-06-29
2013-06-30
2013-07-01
2013-07-02
```

My problem here is that I want to output this on a `JTable`. I tried calling each `string` from the `datelist` like this `System.out.println(arrayImageList.get(2));` but it didn't work. How can I output `datelist` to `JTable` or call every element from `datelist` individually?

```
    final String oldy= ("yyyy-MM-dd");
    final String newy = ("MMMM dd, yyyy");

    SimpleDateFormat formatty = new SimpleDateFormat(oldy);
    java.util.Date datey=null;

    //format the final date output to MMMM-dd-yyyy
    try {
        datey=formatty.parse(datelist);
        java.util.Date newqwe2 = new SimpleDateFormat(oldy).parse(datelist);
        String eqweqwe = new SimpleDateFormat(newy).format(newqwe2);

        ArrayList<String> arrayImageList = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> strlist2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        arrayImageList.addAll((List<String>) Arrays.asList(eqweqwe));                                                                   

        for(int i = 0; i < arrayImageList.size(); i++){
            strlist2.add(arrayImageList.get(i));

            System.out.println(strlist2.get(2));
```

Sorry for the long post but I just want you guys to get whole process in case there is something missing.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you are doing a lot of unnecessary work. If you work with `Calendar` objects you can do that very efficient. Put both dates in objects of `Calendar` and name them `toDate` and `fromDate`. You just run a `while` loop that keeps increasing the `fromDate` until it is larger than `toDate` and print it out.

```
Calendar fromDate;
Calendar toDate;

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

while(fromDate.compareTo(toDate) < 0)
{
   System.out.println(df.format(fromDate.getTime()));
   fromDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
```

You can also use the loop in order to other things (e.g. populate a List or Model for a `JTable`). In  that case just make a list of `String` or `Date` objects and simply place the return from `getTime()` or `format()` in the list/model.

Comment: "Put both dates in objects of Calendar and name them toDate and fromDate. " What do you mean by this?